# RadGrid.Net2 Telerik.WebControls does not display any data even though it did a day ago

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am using the following in my aspx/cs files, and I am not seeing any data. We were using the

```
                <radG:RadGrid ID="TodaysStatsInformation" 
                    OnNeedDataSource="TodayStatsInformation_NeedDataSource" 
                    OnItemDataBound="TodayStatsInformation_ItemDataBound"
                    OnDetailTableDataBind="TodayStatsinformation_DetailTableDataBind"
                    Width="1600px" 
                    PageSize="50" PagerStyle-Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" 
                    EnableAJAXLoadingTemplate="True" 
                    LoadingTemplateTransparency="50" 
                    AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True"
                    runat="server" 
                    GridLines="None" EnableAJAX="True" Skin="WebBlue" 
                    ShowFooter="False"
                    SkinsPath="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/">
                    <AJAXLoadingTemplate>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <img src="/RadControls/AJAX/Skins/Default/loading7.gif" alt="" />
                    </AJAXLoadingTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ClientID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CommandItemDisplay="Top" ShowFooter="True">
                        <FooterStyle>
                            <Font Bold="true"></Font>
                        </FooterStyle>
                        <CommandItemSettings RefreshImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Refresh.gif" AddNewRecordImageUrl="RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/AddRecord.gif"></CommandItemSettings>
                        <CommandItemTemplate>
                            <b>Today's Stats Information&nbsp;</b>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton23" runat="server" CommandName="RebindGrid"><img style="border:0px" alt="" src="/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Refresh.gif"/> Refresh</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                            &nbsp;
                        </CommandItemTemplate>
                        <DetailTables>
                            <radG:GridTableView Skin="WebBlue" SkinsPath="~/admin/os/RadControls/Grid/Skins/" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Normal" DataKeyNames="ClientID" Width="100%" runat="server" Name="ClientDetail" GridLines="Horizontal" BorderColor="White">
                                <ParentTableRelation>
                                    <radG:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="ClientID" MasterKeyField="ClientID" />
                                </ParentTableRelation>
                                <Columns>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True"  SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ClientName" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="ClientName" SortExpression="ClientName" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Client Name">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True"  SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalOrders" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalOrders" SortExpression="TotalOrders" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Orders">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalPieces" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalPieces" SortExpression="TotalPieces" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Pieces">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="AverageOrder" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="AverageOrder" SortExpression="AverageOrder" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Avg Order" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="AveragePieces" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="AveragePieces" SortExpression="AveragePieces" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Avg Pieces" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="GrossProduct" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="GrossProduct" SortExpression="GrossProduct" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Gross Product" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ProductDiscount" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="ProductDiscount" SortExpression="ProductDiscount" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Product Discount" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="SubTotal" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="SubTotal" SortExpression="SubTotal" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Subtotal" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalShipping" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalShipping" SortExpression="TotalShipping" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Shipping" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalTax" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalTax" SortExpression="TotalTax" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Tax" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="GrandTotal" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="GrandTotal" SortExpression="GrandTotal" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Grand Total" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="InProgress" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="InProgress" SortExpression="InProgress" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="In Progress">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ShipCleared" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="ShipCleared" SortExpression="ShipCleared" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Ship Cleared">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="OrdersShipped" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="OrdersShipped" SortExpression="OrdersShipped" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Orders Shipped">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalShipped" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalShipped" SortExpression="TotalShipped" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Shipped" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalCredits" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalCredits" SortExpression="TotalCredits" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Credits" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="NetShipments" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="NetShipments" SortExpression="NetShipments" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Net Shipments" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                                    </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </radG:GridTableView>
                        </DetailTables>
                        <Columns>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ClientName" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" DataType="System.String" UniqueName="ClientName" SortExpression="ClientName" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Client Name">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalOrders" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalOrders" SortExpression="TotalOrders" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Orders">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalPieces" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalPieces" SortExpression="TotalPieces" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Pieces">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="AverageOrder" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="AverageOrder" SortExpression="AverageOrder" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Avg Order" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                        <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalTax" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalTax" SortExpression="TotalTax" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Tax" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="GrandTotal" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="GrandTotal" SortExpression="GrandTotal" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Grand Total" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="InProgress" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="InProgress" SortExpression="InProgress" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="In Progress">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="ShipCleared" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="ShipCleared" SortExpression="ShipCleared" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Ship Cleared">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="OrdersShipped" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="OrdersShipped" SortExpression="OrdersShipped" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Orders Shipped">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalShipped" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalShipped" SortExpression="TotalShipped" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Shipped" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="TotalCredits" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="TotalCredits" SortExpression="TotalCredits" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Total Credits" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                            <radG:GridBoundColumn ReadOnly="True" SortAscImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortAsc.gif" DataField="NetShipments" FilterImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/Filter.gif" UniqueName="NetShipments" SortExpression="NetShipments" SortDescImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/WebBlue/SortDesc.gif" HeaderText="Net Shipments" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
                            </radG:GridBoundColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="False">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="19px"></HeaderStyle>
                        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                        <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="False">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                        </RowIndicatorColumn>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </radG:RadGrid>
```

This is the CS File:

```
protected void TodayStatsInformation_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            var c = new clients();
            ClearRunningTotals();

            var active = !(Request.Params["A"] != null && Request.Params["A"] == "0");

            if (!e.IsFromDetailTable)
            {
                TodaysStatsInformation.MasterTableView.DataSource = c.GetTodaysStats(DateFilter.GetStartDateDT(), DateFilter.GetEndDateDT(), active);
            }
        }
```

again this used to work just fine before, so I don't know what I changed to make it stop working.

I have searched on Google for a couple of hours now to no end.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that someone at my workplace had changed the DLL to the wrong version.